# How to call appropriate Item Processor for different records?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a flat file containing different records(header, record and footer)

```
HR,...
RD,...
FR,...
```

ItemReader

```
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader reader(@Value("#{jobParameters['inputFileName']}") String inputFileName) {
        FlatFileItemReader reader = new FlatFileItemReader();
        reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(inputFileName));
        reader.setLineMapper(patternLineMapper());
        return reader;
    }
```

```
    @Bean
    public LineMapper patternLineMapper() {
        PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper patternLineMapper = new PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper<>();
        tokenizers = new HashMap<String, LineTokenizer>();
        try {
            tokenizers.put("HR*", headerLineTokenizer());
            tokenizers.put("RD*", recordLineTokenizer());
            tokenizers.put("FR*", footerLineTokenizer());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        fieldSetMappers = new HashMap<String, FieldSetMapper>();
        fieldSetMappers.put("HR*", new HeaderFieldSetMapper());
        fieldSetMappers.put("RD*", new RecordFieldSetMapper());
        fieldSetMappers.put("FR*", new FooterFieldSetMapper());
        patternLineMapper.setTokenizers(tokenizers);
        patternLineMapper.setFieldSetMappers(fieldSetMappers);
        return patternLineMapper;
    }
```

They are working fine and spring batch calls the appropriate reader for each record the problem is when it comes to item processor I want to use the same approach I get `java.lang.ClassCastException` cuz spring batch try to map domain object [returned from reader] to `java.lang.String`

ItemProcessor

```
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemProcessor processor() {

        ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor processor = new ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor();
        PatternMatchingClassifier<ItemProcessor> classifier = new PatternMatchingClassifier<>();
        Map<String, ItemProcessor> patternMap = new HashMap<>();
        patternMap.put("HR*", new HeaderItemProcessor());
        patternMap.put("RD*", new RecordItemProcessor());
        patternMap.put("FR*", new FooterItemProcessor());
        classifier.setPatternMap(patternMap);
        processor.setClassifier(classifier);
        return processor;
    }
```

I also used `BackToBackPatternClassifier` but it turns out it has a bug and when I use generics like `ItemWriter<Object>` I get an exception Couldn't Open File. the question is 
**How can I make ItemProcessor that handles different record types returned from Reader??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that the classifier you use in the `ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor` is based on a String pattern and not a type. What really should happen is something like:

The reader returns a specific type of items based on the input pattern, something like:

- HR* -> HRType
- RD* -> RDType
- FR* -> FRType

This is what you have basically done on the reader side. Now on the processing side, the processor will receive objects of type `HRType`, `RDType` and `FRType`. So the classifier should not be based on String as input type, but on the item type, something like:

```
    Map<Object, ItemProcessor> patternMap = new HashMap<>();
    patternMap.put(HRType.class, new HeaderItemProcessor());
    patternMap.put(RDType.class, new RecordItemProcessor());
    patternMap.put(FRType.class, new FooterItemProcessor());
```

This classifier uses `Object` type because your `ItemReader` returns a raw type. I would **not** recommend using raw types and `Object` type in the classifier. What you should do is:

1. create a base class of your items and a specific class for each type
2. Make the reader return items of type `<? extends BaseClass>`
3. Use a `org.springframework.classify.SubclassClassifier` in your `ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor`

Comment: The thing I wanted to be sure about that I can't use ```PatternMatchingClassifier``` with type object because it expects to get ```java.lang.String``` @Mahmoud

Comment: Could you show small POC how the code will work?