# How could I achieve abstraction in all different batch phases?

Tags: spring-batch

I want to achieve abstraction on all the records I read and process in spring batch.

I have a batch file that contains the following

```
HR* -> HRType
RD* -> RDType
FR* -> FRType
```

each on of these types have many children classes Let's see I have parent class called `Header` and children classes `Header1`, `Header2` and `Header3`. the same for Record and Footer.

How can I make a good level of abstraction for `FlatFileItemReader`, `ItemProcessor` and `FlatFileItemWriter` to deal with a different batch file types. Note that I will process consistent files meaning that I will have a file that only contains `Header1`, `Record1` and `Footer1`.

Comment: is this related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58361678?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Actually I have done what you've described there. but I still have another level of abstraction that should be done. How can I make spring batch call the appropriate reader according to the line he is reading? I mean that it will match the parent class but each record has it's own names for the ```lineTokenizer```. How can I handle this?

Comment: `call the appropriate reader` I'm not sure you need multiple readers and call the appropriate one. A flat file item reader with a `PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer` would probably work for you.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine this ```PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer``` will classify header, record and footer types and its working fine with this. In case it classified the record as HRType I have many children for HRType and each one has its own lineTokenizer names. How can I make spring batch call appropriate HRType in this case?!

Comment: I'm thinking to add batch job for each batch type. I mean suppose I have ```developer``` and ```designers``` batches instead of thinking about abstraction for the common records between them I will make a two different jobs with ```reader```, ```processor``` and ```writer```?!

Comment: I would also create a job for each type and keep it simple rather than trying to abstract things to another level.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I'm asking if there was any to achieve that abstraction in spring batch?

Comment: No, not to my knowledge.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I have chosen to make job for each batch type now trying to abstract the config because they almost use the same ```reader``` ```writer``` and ```processor```. will differ in the  ```LineTokenizer``` and other specific fields which I made them abstract and each child config will provide it's own. Now having the step and job at the parent? How can I change job name in the child classes? any clues?!